# Error when installing Odoo on Mac with Python 3.10

Tags: python, odoo

I'm following [this tutorial](https://henrytirla.medium.com/how-to-install-odoo-14-on-mac-os-acb27e074102) to install Odoo 15 in Mac with Python 3.10, but I get this error when running `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '(cd  "/private/var/folders/ht/sqtnbdnx7r5562trfyn3827w0000gn/T/pip-install-qiz3m1g1/gevent_22fc5c60d97046e4bea11df299f9facf/deps/c-ares"  && if [ -r include/ares_build.h ]; then cp include/ares_build.h include/ares_build.h.orig; fi   && sh ./configure --disable-dependency-tracking -C CFLAGS="-Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g"  && cp src/lib/ares_config.h include/ares_build.h "$OLDPWD"   && cat include/ares_build.h   && if [ -r include/ares_build.h.orig ]; then mv include/ares_build.h.orig include/ares_build.h; fi) > configure-output.txt' returned non-zero exit status 77.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gevent
Failed to build gevent
ERROR: Could not build wheels for gevent, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I haven't found absolutely any document addressing the error I'm getting

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70436935/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-gevent-which-is-required-to-install-pyproject) found a relevant question they resolved by downgrading python version

Comment: @MuhammadYusuf I have tried it, but I get a different error in the insallation

Comment: @HuLuViCa Odoo uses [deprecated collection aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71130842/attributeerror-module-collections-has-no-attribute-set) which was removed in Python 3.10 so you can't use it.

Comment: Please show the error message

Answer (score -1):

you need to install these [pyproject](https://pypi.org/project/pyproject/) [projects](https://pypi.org/project/projects/) and be carefully about which python you are using '2' or '3'

```
pip install pyproject projects
```